Need suggestions to bypass 5 alphanumeric CAPTCHA with scratchy noises bg
I'm currently trying to bypass this kind of captcha by using Tesseract v5.5 model but I'm not suceeding.

In the image we cn identify the captcha "w5779", but in the best result I had using Tesseract I only got "w-" as result.
I've tried a few different approaches based on image processing techniques in order to minimize the scratching noises but they didn't work. Below are some of the techniques I've tried:
captcha_image = Image.open(captcha_image_path)
captcha_image_cv = np.array(captcha_image)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(captcha_image_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
                                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
denoised_image = cv2.medianBlur(threshold_image, 3)
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(denoised_image, None, iterations=1)
processed_image = Image.fromarray(dilated_image)
captcha_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_image, config="--psm 8")

Any advices or other tool recommendation to bypass this kind of captcha?
Obs: this is for learning only so I'd try to avoid paid solutions for solving the captcha (as 2captcha etc).

A text recognizing tool is failing to recognise something specifically designed to not be recognized by a machine. Captchas would not exist if you could so easily bypass them.
